# Quartz .net IStatefulJob - remove triggers?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I created a job that implements IStatefulJob and according to the quartz docs

```
"if a job is stateful, and a trigger attempts to 'fire' the job while it is already
executing, the trigger will block (wait) until the previous execution completes"
```

Is there anyway way to remove the block and kill the newly fired instance of the job?

The job I am running can have wildly different run times based on the amount of data behind it and I am concerned that if we have a number of jobs waiting to run that it could have a negative effect...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. As a job implementor you are responsible for making sure that job will keep track whether it has reached its time limit of 'good behavior'. Normally there's no need as jobs take somewhat expected time to complete.

Same goes when you want to interrupt all jobs in scheduler, you need to implement IInterruptableJob and set flag that your main job loop watches.

You can always rethink the design. It shouldn't be problem to queue same job as it has the same duty to do. With misfire instructions you can configure misfired (queued too long) instanced to be discarded and wait for the next fire time.